# Are English crush and Russian крушить related?

Tags: etymology

I wonder whether English *crush* and Russian крушить (*krushit'*, "to crush") related?

Comment: Obviously yes, they mean the same thing, and have similar sounds. You presumably mean "do they derive from the same historical source". "Relatedness" isn't just about etymology.

Answer (score 6):

The Slavic *k* cannot correspond to the Germanic *k* due to the [Grimm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law), Slavic *kr* corresponds to the Germanic *hr*, e. g.:

Rus. *krug* 'circle' : Angl.-Sax. *hring* 'ring'

Rus. *krov'* 'blood' : Old Isl. *hrár* 'raw'

Rus. *krasa* 'beauty' : Old Isl. *hróðr* 'glory'

The two words are not related.

Comment: But is English *crush* believed to derive from PIE? According to [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/1222/mode/2up) *crush* derives from a French word with Romance cognates whose origin is only conjectured to be Germanic, based on a known MHG word derived from a hypothetical OHG *chrosan*. And what is the origin of the Russian? Might it be borrowed?

Comment: @StoneyB - The Russian _krushit'_ is by no means a borrowing, it has many other words of the same root in Russian, it is derived from the noun _krokha_ 'a crumb', which has cognates in the Baltic languages, Lithuanian _krušà_, Latvian _krusa_ both meaning 'hail', and in Greek, _κρούω_ 'to crush, to knock'.

Comment: By the way, from where crumb and crash come?

Comment: @Yellow Sky but Russian word крах is a borrowing.

Comment: @Anixx - Etymology of [crumb](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=crumb&searchmode=none) and [crush](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=crush&searchmode=none). The Russian крах is a borrowing from German _Krach_ which comes from Middle High German _krachen_, from Old High German _krahhōn_, from Proto-Germanic _*krakōną_, cognate with Old English _cracian_, Modern English [_crack_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crack#English). All these words are also not related to one another and not related to _crush_ and _krushit'_.

Comment: Are English crash and German Krach related?

Comment: @Anixx - No, _crash_ is onomatopoeia.